# extract x: $((x+y)^n - x^n)^{1/n}$ expressed in the form $ba^{c}$ where all that matters is b contains x

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, discrete-mathematics, continuity

I've done a bit of calculus/diff.eq./lin.alg. in the past. But that was a long time ago and to be honest I was always better at the actual applying than the pure math.

Anyway, I have a function which I am trying to get into a certain form. I want to do this by isolating/extracting one variable.

I've been trying on paper, Mathematica, Wolfram|Alpha and it's just not making sense to me anymore.

Here's the function:

$$((x+y)^n - x^n)^{1/n}$$

And I'm trying to extract the x out of this so I get something of the form:

$$xa^\text{exponent}$$

Whatever the exponent is or 'a' is or if x has any +something/-something/divided by/exponents, or even if 'a' still contains x's I want x times something to an exponent.

What I have come up with myself so far is driving me mad: I get two forms for 'a' depending on if I do

$$(xa)^{1/n}$$

or

$$x(a^{1/n})$$

As I said, I am really rusty and tried a lot of things which I think are oh-so wrong, but this is what I got trying to extracate x:

$$x^n ((1+((1/x)y)^n -1)^{1/n}$$

OR

$$x^n ((((1/x) + ((1/(x^n))y))^n)-1)^{1/n}$$

I'm not too proud to say I even got:

$$x((1+(1/x)y)^n - x(1/n))^{1/n}$$

I'm doing this all for a hobby programming project of mine (lead android programmer) and I just can't get it to  work out ... plus I would like to be sure the answer is correct!

If it helps, $x$,$y$ and $n$ are all positive integers. $y<x$ and $y\geq 1$, $x\geq3$ and $n\geq2$.

Comment: Please use MathJax in your post and make your post more direct and clear...

Comment: "x(a^(1/n))!!!" Do you mean the triple factorial, the factorial of the double factorial, or yet something else?

Comment: @AndrewLi This is my first post here and I would love to! I know Latex but have never heard of MathJAx ... gotta link to where I would find out more quickly?

Comment: [Here's a good mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) - it's not dissimilar to LaTeX

Comment: @MacD it's LaTeX for JavaScript. Just enclose your LaTeX with dollar signs (or double depending on display style): `$\sin \theta$`.

Comment: @Arnaud  To write, for example "x^(1/n)$, you need to use `x^{1/n}` to render.  Just slapping dollar signs around `$x^(1/n)$` yields $x^(1/n)$.  I corrected most all the exponents following your "mathjax-ifying"

Comment: @amWhy Yes I know that, but if you don't save your edits regularly, then it becomes impossible because of others possibly editing at the same time. For instance here I couldn't save the `$` around the inline $x$ and $a$s

Comment: @AndrewLi and B. Mehta  and Arnaud Mortier ... I have no idea who edited my post to add the dollahdollah bills, but thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, MacD!

Comment: I was just looking for you to try to PM you and thank you: @amWhy  Thanks!

Comment: Arnaud  Doing a complete and thorough edit, once, or maybe with a quickie edit if needed is better than requiring 4, 5, 6, or more successive edits on a problem

Comment: I thank you all :) I now knew enough to at least correct one thing myself (the "eq. or eq:". line gave an interesting misprint :P)

Comment: @amWhy I honestly don't understand why, given than your thorough edit is more likely to end up being impossible to save. It is a complete waste of time.

Comment: @Arnaud  I don't understand what you mean, unless you expect the question's deletion?  In any case, don't edit unless you're prepared to do a thorough edit.  If doing a thorough edit is not worth your time, don't botch an attempt to edit, rendering, as you did, a very difficult version of the question.  I mainly edited only to correct the errors in the exponents that you made.

Comment: @amwhy I didn't make these errors, they were there, and I was just about to correct them when you came. Anyway,  it happened to me several times to lose a thorough edit just because in the meantime someone changed a thing or two, resulting in an error message and edit gone.

Comment: Sorry, you did by surrounding everything that looked like a formula, equation, etc, with dollar signs.  That was lazy.  But I do understand the frustration of working hard to thoroughly edit, when another edit overrides your edit (that is due to the asker making an edit to their own question).  Else, if one's edit is more thorough than anothers, one's edits will trump.

Comment: $((x+y)^n - x^n)^{1/n} = x a^\text{exponent}$ is not possible in general, e.g. choose $n>0$ and $y>0$ and you will get a contradiction with $x=0$. But of course you can use the trivial form $x\cdot\exp((1/n) \ln((x+y)^n - x^n) - \ln x)$ .

Answer (score 3):

How about
$$((x+y)^n-x^n)^{1/n}=\left(x^n\frac{(x+y)^n}{x^n}-x^n\right)^{1/n}=(x^n)^{1/n}\left(\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)^n-1\right)^{1/n}=x\left(\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)^n-1\right)^{1/n},$$
and since $a^x=e^{x\log a}$ (since $x\log a = \log a^x$ and $e^{\log x}=x$) then this is equivalent to
$$x\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)^n-1\right)\right)\equiv ba^c,$$
so $b=x$, $a=e$, and $c$ is the exponent of $a=e$. Note that $\exp(z)\equiv e^z$.

Comment: Your answer was just a few minutes later than Connor's! But thank you very much! Your exponent example was nice to see :)

Answer (score 2):

Your given equation is equivalent to $$\sqrt[n]{\binom{n}{1} x^{n-1} y + \binom{n}{2} x^{n-2}y^2 + \cdots + \binom{n}{n} y^n}$$
which you could rewrite into $$x \left[ \binom{n}{1} \frac{y}{x} + \binom{n}{2} \frac{y^2}{x^2} + \cdots + \binom{n}{n} \frac{y^n}{x^n} \right]^{1/n}$$
or possibly more usefully as $$ x \left[ \left( \frac{y}{x} + 1\right)^n - 1 \right]^{1/n} $$ but I doubt there's any better simplification.

Answer (score 1):

Consideration of the issue function
$$f(x,y,n) = x\left(\left(1+\dfrac yx\right)^n-1\right)^{\frac1n}\tag1$$
in the form of
$$f(x,y,n) = x a^{\text{exponent}}$$
is equivalent to looking for the presentation
$$\left(1+\dfrac{y}x\right)^n-1 = a^b.\tag2$$
Exact approach is $b=1$ and the form $(1),$ wherein $(2)$ allows factorization
$$\left(1+\dfrac{y}x\right)^{2k+1}-1 = \left(\dfrac{y}x+1-1\right) {\left(\left(\dfrac{y}x+1\right)^2-2\left(\dfrac{y}x+1\right)\cos\dfrac{2\pi}{2k+1}+1\right)}\times
{\left(\left(\dfrac{y}x+1\right)^2-2\left(\dfrac{y}x+1\right)\cos\dfrac{4\pi}{2k+1}+1\right)}\dots
\times\left(\left(\dfrac{y}x+1\right)^2-2\left(\dfrac{y}x+1\right)\cos\dfrac{2k\pi}{2k+1}+1\right),$$
or
$$\left(1+\dfrac{y}x\right)^{2k+1}-1 = \dfrac{y}x {\left(\left(\dfrac{y}x\right)^2+4\left(\dfrac{y}x+1\right)\sin^2\dfrac{\pi}{2k+1}\right)}\times
{\left(\left(\dfrac{y}x\right)^2+4\left(\dfrac{y}x+1\right)\sin^2\dfrac{2\pi}{2k+1}\right)}\dots
\left(\left(\dfrac{y}x\right)^2+4\left(\dfrac{y}x+1\right)\sin^2\dfrac{k\pi}{2k+1}\right),\tag3$$
in the case of odd $n=2k+1,$
and
$$\left(1+\dfrac{y}x\right)^{2k}-1 = \left(\left(\dfrac{y}x+1\right)^k-1\right)\left(\left(\dfrac{y}x+1\right)^k+1\right)\tag4$$
in the case of even $n=2k.$

And there are approximations
$$\left(1+\dfrac{y}x\right)^n\approx e^{(ny)/x},\quad f(x,y,n)\approx x\left( e^{\frac {ny}x}-1\right)^{\frac1n},\quad \text{ if }\ \dfrac {ny}x \approx 1,\ n >> 1,\tag{5}$$
$$\left(1+\dfrac{y}x\right)^n-1 \approx \dfrac {ny}x,\quad f(x,y,n)\approx x\left(\dfrac{ny}x\right)^{\frac1n},\quad \text{ if }\ \dfrac {ny}x << 1.\tag{6}$$
On the other hand, the polynomial $(2)$ reduces to the degree $(n-1),$ so the consideration in the form of
$$f(x,y,n) = x^{\frac{n-1}n} a^{\frac1n}\tag7$$
can be useful too. In this case
$$a = x\left(\left(1+\dfrac{y}x\right)^n-1\right),\tag8$$
$$a = y\left(n +\binom{n}{2}\dfrac yx +\dots + \binom{n}{n-2}\left(\dfrac yx\right)^{n-3} + n\left(\dfrac yx\right)^{n-2} + \left(\dfrac yx\right)^{n-1}\right).\tag9$$

Comment: Awesome answer, Yuri! But Connor was earlier and he did have qa correct answer. But I do want to thank you very much for your comprehensive answer!